# Outlook 2010 Calendar not displaying correct meetings and appoint

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

When viewing the calendar in OWA or if a different user views the calendar it is fine. But when viewing it in Outlook 2010 the meetings and appointments are all wrong.

Some are on the wrong dates, some take up an entire day. Some meetings show the time being 10:01-10:31 instead of 10-10:30. I have removed all items from the calendar and allowed it to resync, same issue. I have created a new profile, same.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do your regional settings look like?

Comment: Time is correct. Eastern Daylight time. Its set to automatically adjust for daylight savings time.

Comment: Your Exchange user may be corrupt (though I'm not sure how this is possible, given the evidence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user must have changed the view of the calendars in Outlook. To fix it I simply click the reset view under the view category.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Outlook for the user on a different machine and verify that it isn't a borked install of Outlook on that particular workstation.  As far as I can remember, OWA is pulling the same info that Outlook would, so there shouldn't be any reason for the two to show different things.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas guys. I was actually able to figure it out. It was something petty. The user must have changed the view of the calendars in Outlook. To fix it I simply click the reset view under the view category. Thanks for all the help.